# Prevent the dragover event to be triggered from inside TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How do I prevent the `dragover` event to be triggered from the editor. `ed.contentDocument` is the iframe's document object.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: ["media", "paste"],
  paste_data_images: true,
  height: 400,
  paste_enable_default_filters: true,
  init_instance_callback: (ed) => {
    ed.dom.bind(ed.contentDocument, "dragover", () => {
      console.log('dragover')
    })
  }
})
```

What I need is this:

1. When users drag an image from outside the editor trigger the event.
2. When users drag an image from the editor prevent the event.

I'm aware of event delegation but after wasting so many hours I'm out of ideas.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/dadogah/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer here for someone who has the same problem. The solution was pretty simple. Fortunately the mimetype can be accessed through the `DataTransfer` object.

So, if the item is of kind `file` then we're dragging from outside, otherwise is of kind `string` as in an URL.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: ["media", "paste"],
  paste_data_images: true,
  height: 400,
  paste_filter_drop: false,
  init_instance_callback: (ed) => {
    ed.contentDocument.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
      var items = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.items);
      var allItemsFiles = items.map(item => item.kind).every(item => item === "file")

      if(allItemsFiles) {
        console.log('from outside');
        return;
      }

      console.log('from inside')
    })
  }
})
```